# Cross compiling GCC for linux i686-elf

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, glibc, elf

I am trying to cross compile the gcc for linux - i686-elf platform from windows PC. As per the toolchain steps, I have successfully compiled:

1. binutils using

   `/binutils-x.y.z/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror`
2. basic gcc using

   `gcc-x.y.z/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers`
3. linux headers using

   `make headers_install ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE=i386-linux- INDTALL_HDR_PATH=my/path/`

NOW, I am trying to compile the 'glibc' core c library using

```
`CC=${TARGET}-gcc ../glibc-2.29/configure --target=$TARGET --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=$PREFIX --with-headers=my/path/`
```

### BUT I am getting the follwing errors :(

```
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/elf/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/not-cancel.h:57: undefined reference to `__GI___close_nocancel'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `invalid_name':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/elf/../sysdeps/posix/opendir.c:43: undefined reference to `rtld_errno'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `__fxstatat64':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/elf/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fxstatat64.c:55: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/elf/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fxstatat64.c:37: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `__closedir':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/posix/closedir.c:52: undefined reference to `__GI___close_nocancel'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/posix/closedir.c:36: undefined reference to `rtld_errno'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `__readdir':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/posix/readdir.c:41: undefined reference to `rtld_errno'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/posix/readdir.c:76: undefined reference to `rtld_errno'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/posix/readdir.c:71: undefined reference to `rtld_errno'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `__rewinddir':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/posix/rewinddir.c:31: undefined reference to `__lseek'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `__getdents':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getdents.c:96: undefined reference to `__lseek64'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getdents.c:99: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getdents.c:54: undefined reference to `rtld_errno'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `__fdopendir':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/posix/fdopendir.c:32: undefined reference to `__GI___fxstat64'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/posix/fdopendir.c:41: undefined reference to `__GI___fcntl64_nocancel'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/posix/fdopendir.c:36: undefined reference to `rtld_errno'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/dirent/../sysdeps/posix/fdopendir.c:46: undefined reference to `rtld_errno'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `__libc_scratch_buffer_set_array_size':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/malloc/scratch_buffer_set_array_size.c:41: undefined reference to `rtld_errno'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `__mmap':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/misc/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mmap.c:39: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/misc/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mmap.c:42: undefined reference to `rtld_errno'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `munmap':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/misc/../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:78: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `__mprotect':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/misc/../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:78: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `uname':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/posix/../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:78: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `__libc_sigaction':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigaction.c:58: undefined reference to `rtld_errno'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `__sigaction':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/signal/../nptl/sigaction.c:26: undefined reference to `rtld_errno'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: in function `setitimer':
/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/time/../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:78: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/ld.so.new: hidden symbol `__lseek64' isn't defined
/home/MyPC/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.4.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:496: /home/MyPC/src/build-glibc/elf/ld.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29/elf'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:258: elf/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/MyPC/src/glibc-2.29'
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to the fact that [glibc can only be built on case-sensitive file systems](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=72). You will have to switch the file system that hosts the build tree into case-sensitive mode.